# How do I parse this sentence using という話?

Tags: grammar, parsing

My question is about how to correctly parse the second line in the below.

> 「しかし廃棄迷宮ですか……いろんなものを捨てていたら最後には溢れちゃいそうです」
>
> 「**廃棄迷宮に果てはなく、一説には異次元に繋がっているという話もあるくらいだぞ**」
>
> 「話が真実だとするとゴミ問題の類は全て解決するんだけどな」

I suppose my question boils down to:

- Does という話 refer to the whole previous statement i.e. 廃棄迷宮に果てはなく、一説には異次元に繋がっている
- Or does it only refer to 一説には異次元に繋がっている

Answer (score 1):

It only refers to 一説には異次元に繋がっている.

The trash dungeon is bottomless (廃棄迷宮に果てはなく). That's presented as established fact. Then the speaker adds some less certain hearsay: And some people even theorize that it's connected to an alternate dimension (一説には異次元に繋がっているという話もあるくらいだ).